# Pass on hyperlink value in one jsp to fetch values in another jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm having a web page(html) like this:

[image: accounts list]

All the records are fetched from database where **Account No** column made hyperlink, which I want to use as input for another jsp where I need to fetch values from database based on that.

```html
<td><center><a href="strtrandetresponse.jsp" value="foracid"> 
<%=rs.getString("foracid")%></form></a></center></td>
<td><center><%=rs.getString("cust_id")%></center></td>
<td><center><%=rs.getString("dormant")%></center></td>
<td><center><%=rs.getString("bsbd")%></center></td>
<td><center><%=rs.getString("others")%></center></td>
<td><center><%=rs.getString("details")%></center></td>
<td><center><input type="button" value="Is Suspicious?" name="submit"/></center></td>
```

On clicking on Account number, it is redirecting to strtrandetresponse.jsp but fetching no value from it.

I'm using below code in strtrandetresponse.jsp

```
<%
    String foracid = request.getParameter("foracid");
    try {
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Is the a tag 'value' processed by your JSP engine? It looks sensible, but it's not a normal `a` tag attribute AFAIK. You also have a stray close form tag in there.